# I created a class, and am unable to load values into its array var

Tags: php, arrays

The problem is that the addData function adds data to all variables but not to keywords array. As far as I can see, the keywords[1] is blank after the  $keywords[]=$new_value; line. Why??  Here is my code:

```
class comment
{

    var $id;
    var $keywords;
    //some other vars

// This is the constructor function which assigns id property, creates keywords array.
function comment($newID) 
    {
        $this->id = $newID;
        $keywords = array();
    }

// This function is used to add data to one of the object's properties.
function addData ($prop, $new_value) 
{   // Convert the property name to lower case.
    $prop = strtolower($prop);
    if ($prop=='keywords'){
        $keywords[]=$new_value;
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->$prop = $new_value;
     }
}

}
```

Comment: I have tried the John Conde recommendation, but get the PHP Syntax Check: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in your code on line 117 $this->$keywords[]=$new_value; –  Sniker j

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `$this` keyword which makes your `$keywords` variable just a local variable instead of a class member:

```
$keywords[]=$new_value;
```

should become

```
$this->keywords[]=$new_value;
```

You did the same thing in your `comment()` method.

FYI, using `var` to declare class member variables has been obsolete for a long time. You should be using `public`, `protected`, and `private` as appropriate.

Comment: I have tried the John Conde recommendation, but get the PHP Syntax Check: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in your code on line 117
$this->$keywords[]=$new_value;

Comment: And thank you, I will make them approbraitely typed vars... thank you

Comment: You probably have a syntax error before that line which is causing that error